# NSTextField losing Focus/FirstResponder when mouse leaves NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nstextfield, first-responder

I have a NSTextField in an NSWindow, when I highlight the text to change it, the highlight is blue.  If, while the TextField still has focus, I move my mouse outside of the NSWindow; my NSTextField loses focus and the highlight is now gray.  I basically want to keep focus on the NSTextView no matter where the mouse goes, unless they click outside, hit enter, or hit tab. (End Editing)

Has anybody seen this before or know a solution to the problem?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you maybe use some third-party software to achieve focus-follows-mouse behavior on your Mac?

Comment: No, I don't think so :\  I'm doing some deep debugging to try to find the moment that the TextField loses focus but I'm even having trouble doing that

Comment: Can you reproduce with a new, simple project where you just add a text field to a window, build, and run? Does it also happen if you use your built app from a different user account? You can try setting a breakpoint on `-[NSTextView resignFirstResponder]` and/or `-[NSWindow makeFirstResponder:]` and look at the backtrace for clues as to why it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be a problem with the outside view having a mouseentered event that would take control of the mouse